# Angular HttpInterceptor and HttpClientModule causing infinite requests

Tags: angular, http

I wrote an interceptor to grab a token I send from my server and add it to subsequent requests:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.store.select(selectUser).pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        if (user && user.token) {
          const authRequest = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
            },
          });
          return next.handle(authRequest);
        }
        return next.handle(req);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

As per Angular recommendations, I wrote a separate provider for this interceptor:

```
import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from '../http-interceptors/authInterceptor';
export const authInterceptorProvider: Provider = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true,
};
```

and then provided it to my base component (I'm using the standalone API, so AppComponent is kind of my main):

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    authInterceptorProvider,
    provideState(feedFeature),
    provideState(authFeature),
    provideStore(),
    provideEffects(feedEffects, authEffects),
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideStoreDevtools({
      maxAge: 25,
      logOnly: !isDevMode(),
      autoPause: true,
      trace: false,
      traceLimit: 75,
    }),
  ],
});
```

The behavior is this, if I remove the line:

```
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)
```

the interceptor doesn't work at all, but I do add it, my browser ends up making infinite requests with the interceptor working (I added a console.log).

I checked the request headers and the Auth headers aren't being sent either (user && user.token both exist, the console.log was inside the if statement)

Does anyone know why infinite requests are being sent? And/or why the header isnt being set?

Also, I'm not the best Angular especially with the standalone API, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with adding both:

```
importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule) and provideHttpClient()
```

Comment: Only keep `provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())`, `HttpClientModule` will soon be deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.store.select(selectUser)` is making an API call to get the data, it will again call the interceptor, leading to an infinite loop.

This was solved earlier by Oscar. By making the API call using [HttpBackend](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpBackend) this will skip calling the interceptor when an API call is made.

So the solution will be the code inside `this.store.select(selectUser)` should use `HttpBackend` instead of `HttpClient` which will bypass the interceptor call and prevent the infinite loop!

---

And also `provideHttpClient()` is alone enough to use the `HttpClientMoudule` providers!

---

Also note you can also go for a [`interceptorFn`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptorFn) instead of the old style of creating a class for an interceptor!

Comment: Thanks! And also thanks for the extra tips!

Answer (score 1):

See that always receive a call execute `this.store.select(selectUser)` even when you the bearing is yet done

I imagine should be some like (Code write As IS):

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token=req.headers.get("Authorization") //try get the Authorization

   //if you store the token in the own user

    if (token==selectUser.token)
        return next.handle(req);  //just is authorize
  
   //if you store the token in localStorage   
      const tokenOld: string = localStorage.setItem('token');
      if (token==tokenOld)
        return next.handle(req);  //just is authorize

    return this.store.select(selectUser).pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        if (user && user.token) {
          const authRequest = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
            },
          });
          //you can store the token in the own user
          selectUser.token=`Bearer ${user.token}`;

          //or in localsotrage
          localStorage.setItem('token');

          return next.handle(authRequest).pipe(
              catchError((error) => {
                 if (error.status === 401) { //if token expired
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                 }
                return throwError(error);
              });
          });
        }
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
              catchError((error) => {
                 if (error.status === 401) { //if token expired
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                 }
                return throwError(error);
              });
        })
    );
  }
```